# vue make pagination with custom component (not the b-table)

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vue-component

I see this and implement it exactly as ir
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination

but I want to show the data in my custom component, instead of their table

```html
<Appobject
  v-for="obj in objects"
  :key="obj.id"
  :per-page="perPage"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  :obj="obj"
/>

<b-pagination
  v-model="currentPage"
  :total-rows="rows"
  :per-page="perPage"
  aria-controls="my-table"
></b-pagination>
```

Appobject : is a customized component to show the data

this worked by showing all the list not just the number I set
(props are working and data are sent and the list is shown ,
**the problem with customized pagination**)

what so you suggest for solving this ?